# Probability a sleep kitten can escape falling into a ball pit

Tags: probability, random-walk

A very sleep kitten walks towards the edge of a ball pit. One step forward and they will fall in. Exactly one-third of their steps are towards the edge, while the other two-thirds lead them back to safety. What is the probability that they don't fall in?

I looked at this problem, but it didn't seem to be asking the same thing:
[For this probability question, should I consider him stepping back and then forward again?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1759233/for-this-probability-question-should-i-consider-him-stepping-back-and-then-forw)

I've been looking at some cases (do they step forward or back first), but am still stuck.

Edit: This problem seems to be a duplicate, so I'll post the link to the original:
[Random Walk of a drunk man](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1716418/random-walk-of-a-drunk-man)

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: This is just a bad setting, I suggest editing it

Comment: My father mentioned this as a problem in a 'probability for fun' book of his this very weekend (over his wine or martini). The book solution involved, I recall him saying, a quadratic. With that in mind, how about this: let $p$ prob to move towards cliff , $q$ away, $P$ probability of eventual death. Then $P= p + q P^2$, because either one dies immediately ($p$) or one moves away ($q$), from which one reruns the problem twice ($P^2$), i.e., once eventually back to the edge , and once again to send one eventually over the edge. Comments? (Here $p=1/3$, $q=2/3$, $P=1/2$, or $P=1$!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say implies that doom is $1$ step away, and safety $2$ steps away, and we want to compute the probability of reaching safety, ie she is saved !

Without going into characteristic equations, etc, can do this short problem by examining step by step

There are $4$ points where you could be, $A-B-C-D$ with $D$ signifying doom, $A$ safety and present position $C$

$P(D) = 0$ and $P(A) =1$ are the "boundary conditions", as doom must be avoided and safety ensured

From C, since we don't want doom, with one step the equation is

$c = 0.5b + 0.5*0$ [we don't want doom, and the Pr of getting to $b$ is 0.5]

From B, the equation is $b= 0.5*1 + 0.5c$ [We sure want safety, but may slide back to $c$ with $Pr = 0.5 $]

Solving the equations, we get $c = 1/3$, ie the probability of reaching safety $=1/3$

We might also intuitionally say that as there is $1$ step to doom and $2$ to safety, doom is twice as probable as safety

Answer (score 1):

Try calculating the probability that they will fall off the cliff.
These are the sequences

(F, BFF, BBFFF, ......)

These sequences are infinite, find their probability using geometric series. This holds since we have disjointness and can sum.

As pointed out below the primary challenge then reduces to finding all such sequences.

(*this is an offhand comment, but I believe this should work, if not I will edit/remove later*)

Comment: The general principle works, but there are many more such sequences than you seem to imply. For example, there are $5$ sequences of length $7$ to consider: BBBFFFF, BBFBFFF, BBFFBFF, BFBBFFF, and BFBFBFF. Counting the number of relevant sequences of each odd length $2k+1$ is the main challenge of this approach.

Comment: yes, perhaps I will edit later.